# Is there a $t$-channel process for $q\bar{q} \rightarrow gg$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

Let's consider the process $q\bar{q}\rightarrow gg$. Is the following Feynman diagram allowed:

[image]

I ask because of the following reason: At the upper vertex, the $q$ emits a gluon $g$ and the propagator would then be a $q$, I guess, but at the lower vertex, the propagator would then emit a gluon $g$ and turn into a $\bar{q}$. Would this not be a violation of **electric** charge at the lower vertex, because the gluon $g$ does not have any charge?

Comment: What does the masslessness of a neutral external gluon have to do with charge conservation?  If you think of "time" going from left to right and tilt the propagator a bit to the right (so it goes down and right,), the the quark keeps its charge in the propagator, and annihilates with an external antiquark, thereby always conserving charge. Alternatively, it spits out a gluon and goes backward in time, which is like an antiquark going forward in time.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605183/2451

Comment: Hi MathIsFun. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Hi Qmechanic, I am sorry, you are right, thanks for telling me.